# ASPX becomes blank after Data-source linked

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, visual-studio, telerik

I am unsure as to why this is occurring: When I don't have anything linking to my DB in VS, page loads fine; however, the second I try to link anything from the DB, to the .aspx | The page will not display (Just a white screen). There are no errors displaying, not quite sure what the exact problem is or why it's not displaying the SQL data. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong and I can't see where. (Using VS 2012).

I've tried a few different ways of doing it. -- The following code below, as well as just trying to shorthand/use a little quick fix around it:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" DataTextField="COMBINEDCATEGORY" DataValueField="OPGUIDE_COLLECTIONS_ID" DataSourceId="SqlDataSource1"></telerik:RadComboBox>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [OPGUIDE_VIEW]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The other way I tried it (The preferred way of doing it):

aspx.cs

```
namespace Web
{
    public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable myDataTable = GetDataFromDatabase();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myDataTable);
            if (myDataTable != null)
            {

                //string queryString = "SELECT COMBINEDCATEGORY, FROM OPGUIDE_VIEW";
                //OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(queryString);

                RadComboBox1.DataTextField = "COMBINEDCATEGORY";
                RadComboBox1.DataValueField = "OPGUIDE_COLLECTIONS_ID";

                RadComboBox1.DataSource = myDataTable;
                RadComboBox1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected DataTable GetDataFromDatabase()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(this.DacConnectionString))
            {
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("PKG_OPGUIDE_COLLECTIONDATA.fn_opview", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("OPGUIDE_COLLECTIONS_ID", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("COMBINEDCATEGORY", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
                  //cmd.Parameters.Add("p_cursor_2", OracleDbType.RefCursor, DBNull.Value, ParameterDirection.Output);
                 //  cmd.Parameters.Add("p_cursor_3", OracleDbType.RefCursor, DBNull.Value, ParameterDirection.Output);
                 //  conn.Open();

                    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);

                    try
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        dt = null;
                        throw new NotImplementedException(ex.Message);
                    }
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }

        public string DacConnectionString { get; set; }
    }
}
```

.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web.test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="Styles/styles.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: right;
            width:175px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <p>Test 
        </p>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
                <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this looks like a `PostBack` Issue.. when you hit the `Page_Load` after a postback has been triggered.. when are you ever reloading the `RadComboBox1` try adding some `If IsPostBack { }` code and rebinding the `RadComboBox1` you should probably make a `static declaration of the following `DataTable dt = new DataTable();` or a `protected one` web does not act the same as in windows in regards presenting / binding data...etc..

Comment: remove the <p> tag from around your ComboBox

Comment: @MethodMan I will look that up and try to see what you're talking about. Relatively new to all of this, so have never used much of this before.

Comment: @umer, done. Did nothing.

Comment: did you debug it and see what you receive in myDataTable  after GetDataFromDatabase() is called ?

Comment: @umer Nothing is printing for debug, so not sure where to see that from. -- updated main code to show you how I'm trying to debug.

Comment: not debug like this , i mean to add a breakpoint at your Page_Load funtions and then start debugging , pressing f10 step by step and watch the value inside myDataTable after GetDataFromDatabase() is called

Comment: As soon as I add the combobox or DB connection, debugging shows nothing. At a lose atm as to what's causing it.

Comment: Can you pull that data in a simple GridView first? Just to make sure the issue is not with the data source connection timing out?

Comment: After looking it up further, - I'm using telerik controls, and you need to setup a RadAjaxManager in order for them to display correctly in general. Missing that. - Going to see if that would be the main cause and i'll let you all know.

Comment: Alright. So, turns out. It was that I was missing 'scriptmanager' in my .ASPX. Added that in there, everything worked.